# GSON - Date format

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to have a custom date format in Gson output, but `.setDateFormat(DateFormat.FULL)` doesn't seem to work and it the same with `.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateSerializer())`.

It's like Gson doesn't care about the object "Date" and print it in its way.

How can I change that?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
@Entity
public class AdviceSheet {
  public Date lastModif;
[...]
}

public void method {
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG).create();
   System.out.println(gson.toJson(adviceSheet);
}
```

I always use `java.util.Date`; `setDateFormat()` doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you checked that you are importing correct Date-class in all places? Also code example would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What do you actually see?

Answer (score 352, accepted):

It seems that you need to define formats for both date and time part or use String-based formatting. For example:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .setDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz").create();
```

or [using java.text.DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .setDateFormat(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL).create();
```

or do it with serializers:

I believe that formatters cannot produce timestamps, but this serializer/deserializer-pair seems to work

```
JsonSerializer<Date> ser = new JsonSerializer<Date>() {
  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext 
             context) {
    return src == null ? null : new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime());
  }
};

JsonDeserializer<Date> deser = new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
  @Override
  public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
       JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    return json == null ? null : new Date(json.getAsLong());
  }
};

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, ser)
   .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, deser).create();
```

If using Java 8 or above you should use the above serializers/deserializers like so:

```
JsonSerializer<Date> ser = (src, typeOfSrc, context) -> src == null ? null
            : new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime());

JsonDeserializer<Date> deser = (jSon, typeOfT, context) -> jSon == null ? null : new Date(jSon.getAsLong());
```

Comment: Ok it works better with your way.
But how can I display timestamps with this ?

Comment: I am using Gson 2.2.4 and `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();` works.

Comment: using Gson 2.2.2 and `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();` works

Answer (score 92):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").create();
```

Above format seems better to me as it has precision up to millis.

Comment: @Abhi - Why is quoting 'Z' necessary?

Comment: I tried without quotes and gson threw Exception that the date is not parseable. Does it work for you without quotes?

Comment: ThIs is NOT right solution .. the Z means timezone and it represents UTC timezone, if you hardcode it like this you'll lost that info

Comment: This is 8601 format which is right.  The Z means UTC, but I am not sure how you set the time zone on the Gson object.  That must be set as well or you will get the default time zone I would bet.

Answer (score 6):

As M.L. pointed out, JsonSerializer works here. However, if you are formatting database entities, use java.sql.Date to register you serializer. Deserializer is not needed.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .registerTypeAdapter(java.sql.Date.class, ser).create();
```

This bug report might be related: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=230. I use version 1.7.2 though.

Answer (score 5):

In case if you hate Inner classes, by taking the advantage of functional interface you can write less code in **Java 8** with a lambda expression.

```
JsonDeserializer<Date> dateJsonDeserializer = 
     (json, typeOfT, context) -> json == null ? null : new Date(json.getAsLong());
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class,dateJsonDeserializer).create();
```

Comment: It seems that null check can be omitted (Gson does it itself):
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, (JsonDeserializer) (json, typeOfT, context) -> new Date(json.getAsLong())).create();`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify you format `Gson gson = builder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();`    in this method instead of `yyyy-MM-dd` you can use anyother formats

```
 GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
                            public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                                return new Date(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsLong());
                            }
                        });

                        Gson gson = builder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1529). Currently you either have to set a `timeStyle` as well or use one of the alternatives described in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This won't really work at all. There is no date type in JSON. I would recommend to serialize to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) back and forth (for format agnostics and JS compat). Consider that you have to know which fields contain dates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Gson 2.8.6 and discovered this bug today.

My approach allows all our existing clients (mobile/web/etc) to continue functioning as they were, but adds some handling for those using 24h formats and allows millis too, for good measure.

```
Gson rawGson = new Gson();
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
private class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            return new rawGson.fromJson(json, Date.class);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {}
        String timeString = json.getAsString();
        log.warning("Standard date deserialization didn't work:" + timeString);
        try {
            return fmt.parse(timeString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {}
        log.warning("Parsing as json 24 didn't work:" + timeString);
        return new Date(json.getAsLong());
    }
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer())
    .create();
```

I kept serialization the same as all clients understand the standard json date format.

Ordinarily, I don't think it's good practice to use try/catch blocks to govern flow control, but this should be a fairly rare case.

Comment: "I don't think it's good practice to use try/catch blocks" It is good practice to use them, it is bad if you want to control normal program flow with try/catch.

Comment: Kamil, that is what I meant. But upon rereading my answer, I agree with you that clarification is necessary