# Gson convert from Json to arraylist with date

Tags: java, json, arraylist, gson

I'm having trouble converting json to a java typed arraylist when I included timestamp fields from the database.

Note that without the timestamp fields (the rest of the fields, not shown here), conversion works fine. It's just when I try to include the timestamp fields below that it fails with a com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException.

I've seen answers here about using setDateFormat on a GsonBuilder, e.g [GSON - Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format)

So I tried that, but couldn't make it work. I'm not sure how to do it in this context where I want a typed array list. None of the examples I found was like that.

Here's the code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
        TypeToken<List<Resource>> token = new TypeToken<List<Resource>>() {
        };
        List<Resource> resources = gson.fromJson(response, token.getType());
```

The mapping object has these fields:

```
private Timestamp created;
private Timestamp modified;
```

And corresponding getters and setters:

```
 /**
     * @return the created
     */
    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    /**
     * @param created the created to set
     */
    public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    /**
     * @return the modified
     */
    public Timestamp getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    /**
     * @param modified the modified to set
     */
    public void setModified(Timestamp modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }
```

EDIT:

As requested, here is the full exception message (as much as I got):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2014-03-02 15:33:55
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:35)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at model.DataAccess.getResources(DataAccess.java:82)
    at se.expertinfo.ccmsliteplugin.PluginHelper.doSearch(PluginHelper.java:132)
    at views.SearchView.triggerSearchEvent(SearchView.java:227)
    at views.SearchView.valueChanged(SearchView.java:213)
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(JTree.java:2919)
    at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(JTree.java:3378)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:634)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:1092)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:293)
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(DefaultTreeSelectionModel.java:187)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(JTree.java:1631)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(BasicTreeUI.java:2396)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(BasicTreeUI.java:3612)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressedDND(BasicTreeUI.java:3589)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTreeUI.java:3548)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6502)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-03-02 15:33:55"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:105)
    ... 69 more
```

EDIT 2:

Sample Json (very shortened, the actual result is very long, but the syntax is the same):

```
[
    {
        "id": "16",
        "title": "Warranty 43456",
        "created_by": "Anders Svensson",
        "modified_by": "Anders Svensson",
        "version": "1",
        "version_displayname": "1.0",
        "informationtype": "document",
        "filetype": "xml",
        "base_id": "uuid_03372934-a213-11e3-93de-2b47e5a489c2",
        "resource_id": "uuid_03372934-a213-11e3-93de-2b47e5a489c2",
        "created": "2014-03-02 15:33:55",
        "modified": "2014-03-02 15:34:51",
        "categories": "10,product,Audi A6;9,product,Audi A4;21,subject,Safety;8,product,Audi A3;21,subject,Safety;15,product,Volvo V70"
    },
    {
        "id": "22",
        "title": "Transportation 37337",
        "created_by": "Anders Svensson",
        "modified_by": "Anders Svensson",
        "version": "1",
        "version_displayname": "1.0",
        "informationtype": "document",
        "filetype": "xml",
        "base_id": "uuid_03372b96-a213-11e3-93de-2b47e5a489c2",
        "resource_id": "uuid_03372b96-a213-11e3-93de-2b47e5a489c2",
        "created": "2014-03-02 15:33:55",
        "modified": "2014-03-02 15:34:51",
        "categories": "10,product,Audi A6;12,product,BMW 320;11,product,BMW 120;13,product,BMW 520;8,product,Audi A3;19,subject,Transportation;9,product,Audi A4;19,subject,Transportation"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an appropriate date format for your `Gson` object. For example,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
```

Otherwise it attempts to use some defaults which you can find in the `DateTypeAdapter` class source code.