# Date time format changes when converting from List object data to JSON data using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I've a array list object in which one of the date time field is  2014-06-13 19:05:00, after converting the list object to json object using Google gson it changes to Jun 13, 2014 7:05:00 PM. I don't want it to convert on its own. Any ideas?

```
Gson objGson = new Gson();

String messages = objGson.toJson(listMessages);
```

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Built-in-Serializers-and-Deserializers.

Comment: What's the actual type of the field? If it's a date, try to replace that with a string...

Comment: Its a java.util datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with [GsonBuilder#setDateFormat()](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setDateFormat(int))

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                   .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
```

For more info have a look at [GSON - Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format)

If nothing works then try with [Custom Serialization and Deserialization](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Answer (score 0):

You need to format when you extract date from json.
Alternate solution is:
Add your date to json as strings and get them as strings.