# How can i store DateTime value in Java

Tags: java, json, datetime

I am trying to Map object `Datetime` to `Date` Datatype here is my code:-

```
HolidayResponse holidayResponse=null;
app=(HrmsApp)context.getApplicationContext();
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String Year=app.getHolidayYear();

SettingsManager settings = new SettingsManager(context);
String AuthenticationToken=app.getAuthenticationToken();
HttpGet request=new HttpGet(settings.GetHolidayUrl(Year));
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity=null;
try{

request.setHeader("ApplicationToken",AuthenticationToken);
response = client.execute(request);

entity = response.getEntity();


if (entity != null) {
InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();
String s = CommonTasks.convertStreamToString(inStream);


GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
DateDeserializer ds = new DateDeserializer();
gsonb.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, ds);
Gson gson = gsonb.create();     
Type jsonResponseType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Holiday>>() {
}.getType();

List<Holiday> holidayList= gson.fromJson(s,jsonResponseType);//Here i am mapping the Value getting through json into Holiday


}
}catch (Exception e) {              
e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Here is My Holiday Class

```
public class Holiday {
public String Name;
public String Description;

public Date Holidaydate;
public Holiday()
{}
}
```

My Json Result Sample

```
[{"Name":"New Year's Day","Description":"New Year's Day","Holidaydate":"2014-01-01T00:00:00"}]
```

i am trying to map `Holidaydate` from Json result to Holiday Class `Holidaydate` Property which is `Date` type. 
I am not getting how to parse datetime to date at the time of mapping.
is there anyway then tell me thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write custom serializer:

see following answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonb.create();
```

You could use :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create();
```