# Creating an object with realm createObjectFromJson throws exception if the model contains a Date

Tags: android, realm

I have the following classes for two models:

```
public class A extends RealmObject {
    private String field1;
    private B field2;

    //getters and setters
    //...
}

public class B extends RealmObject {
    private String field3;
    private Date field4;

    //getters and setters
    //...
}
```

I am receiving the following JSON that corresponds to the models:

```
{
    "field1" : "hi",
    "field2" : {
        "field3" : "hi again",
        "field4" : "2015-02-17T00:00:00"
    }
}
```

I am trying to create an A object from the JSON, using `createObjectFromJson(A.class, jsonString)`, but I am getting an exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "2015-02-17T00:00:00"`.

It seems that realm is considering the date as a `long` instead of a `String`. Is there a way to set some kind of date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm only supports two kinds of date formats just yet. You can see them here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/src/main/java/io/realm/internal/android/JsonUtils.java

We do however plan to add support for ISO8061 date formats like yours when we implement V2 of the JSON API. You can follow progress on that here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/682

Until then you will have to convert your timestamps manually or use GSON's dateformatters: [GSON - Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format)