# Serialize Java 8 LocalDate as yyyy-mm-dd with Gson

Tags: java, gson

I am using Java 8 and the latest `RELEASE` version (via Maven) of [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).
If I serialize a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) I get something like this

```
"birthday": {
        "year": 1997,
        "month": 11,
        "day": 25
}
```

where I would have preferred `"birthday": "1997-11-25"`. Does Gson also support the more concise format out-of-the-box, or do I have to implement a custom serializer for `LocalDate`s?

(I've tried `gsonBuilder.setDateFormat(DateFormat.SHORT)`, but that does not seem to make a difference.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format should point you in the right direction.

Comment: You'd most probably need to install a [custom TypeAdapter](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.7)

Comment: Looking at the classes in `com.google.gson.internal.bind` there is no type adapter for `LocalDate` (in gson 2.7).

Comment: @JornVernee Good idea. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I shall accept it.

Comment: @Drux, No that's ok, It doesn't really solve the problem. I think your answer is better for future readers.

Comment: @JornVernee That's fine as well. Thx.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Until further notice, I have implemented a custom serializer like so:

```
class LocalDateAdapter implements JsonSerializer<LocalDate> {

    public JsonElement serialize(LocalDate date, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)); // "yyyy-mm-dd"
    }
}
```

It can be installed e.g. like so:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateAdapter())
        .create();
```

Comment: Note that it is recommended to prefer TypeAdapter over JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer since it reads the JSON data in a streaming way instead of parsing it as an in-memory representation of JsonElements. as Sam Barnum answer .

Answer (score 42):

I use the following, supports read/write and null values:

```
class LocalDateAdapter extends TypeAdapter<LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final LocalDate localDate) throws IOException {
        if (localDate == null) {
            jsonWriter.nullValue();
        } else {
            jsonWriter.value(localDate.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate read(final JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            jsonReader.nextNull();
            return null;
        } else {
            return LocalDate.parse(jsonReader.nextString());
        }
    }
}
```

Registered as @Drux says:

```
return new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateAdapter())
        .create();
```

**EDIT 2019-04-04** A simpler implementation

```
private static final class LocalDateAdapter extends TypeAdapter<LocalDate> {
    @Override
    public void write( final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final LocalDate localDate ) throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.value(localDate.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate read( final JsonReader jsonReader ) throws IOException {
        return LocalDate.parse(jsonReader.nextString());
    }
}
```

Which you can add `null` support to by registering the `nullSafe()` wrapped version:

```
new GsonBuilder()
      .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateAdapter().nullSafe())
```

Comment: Edit: Added call to `jsonReader.nextNull()` to correctly consume `null` values.

Comment: your edit hasn't been added. what was the fix exactly?

Comment: I get: Class 'LocalDateAdapter' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'write(JsonWriter, T)' in 'TypeAdapter'" when trying to use this code?

Answer (score 14):

Kotlin version which supports serializing and deserializing:

```
class LocalDateTypeAdapter : TypeAdapter<LocalDate>() {

    override fun write(out: JsonWriter, value: LocalDate) {
        out.value(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(value))
    }

    override fun read(input: JsonReader): LocalDate = LocalDate.parse(input.nextString())
}
```

Register with your GsonBuilder. Wrap using `nullSafe()` for `null` support:

```
GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate::class.java, LocalDateTypeAdapter().nullSafe())
```

Comment: Perfect this works well for Kotlin projects. Thanks very much!

Comment: Doesn't work with sub-objects (e.g. List of LocalDates)

Answer (score 1):

Reported upstream as https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1059 . Current suggestion from the upstream is to use the https://github.com/gkopff/gson-javatime-serialisers addon.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason using the above classes with .nullSafe() didn't work me as I still got this exception with JDK 17 and Gson:

```
Unable to make field private final java.time.LocalDate java.time.LocalDateTime.date accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time"
```

so I used this custom TypeAdapter with null checks:

```
public class LocalDateTimeTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final LocalDateTime localDate) throws IOException {
        if (localDate == null) {
            jsonWriter.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        jsonWriter.value(localDate.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime read(final JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        if (jsonReader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            jsonReader.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(jsonReader.nextString()).toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get: Class 'LocalDateTimeTypeAdapter' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'write(JsonWriter, T)' in 'TypeAdapter'" when trying to use this code?