# reading json file in java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, command-prompt

I am making a simple phone book system where user and admin inputs via command prompt.
I am using a login.json file that has got just this -

{
"username" : "admin", 
"password" : "12345"
}

I want to know whats the best way in java 8 now to read the json file and check if the user is admin or not.

I would also want to know how can i store the DOB given by a user in java 8 LocalDate API, if we can.
I have a model user class that has all the fields but not sure how the LocalDate from java 8 would help me set the date passed from command prompt, seems we have to do some parsing there ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will this help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998203/919158 to read json? Is DOB coming in JSON file?

Comment: additionally to the post above if you use gson for parsing you can register an Adapter for LocalDate [serialize-java-8-localdate-as-yyyy-mm-dd-with-gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192945/serialize-java-8-localdate-as-yyyy-mm-dd-with-gson)

Comment: @kann DOB is coming from console entered by user,
but i think i did it using - 
System.out.println("Please provide DOB of the user (mm/dd/yyyy) : ");
   String dateString = s.next();
   SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"); 
   try {
    Date dateOfBirth= df.parse(dateString);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: @manvendradubey I just Shaw your question but could you please clear me, how user enters input from command line(one-by-one/json file?) e.g. enter username then you read it and then enter pass again read that like that and how you get above mentioned json?

Comment: @SandeepTiwari
i am reading it line by line from console using FastReader class, but the json is just a hardcoded file that has user name and pass to validate if the user entered the admin credential or not, that is it