# Android Writing and reading LocalDate to and from SharedPreferences trouble

Tags: java, android, gson, sharedpreferences, localdate

I'm running into an issue when trying to store a `LocalDate` in `SharedPreferences`. Using the Gson library I turn a list of `Task.java` (custom class) instances into a string and write it to SharedPreferences. The Task instances contain a LocalDate variable. When retrieving that LocalDate variable, it always returns an empty string or date set to 0000-00-00.

When writing & reading only a LocalDate for testing I run into the same problem.

This is the code for trying it out:

```
LocalDate testDate = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println("TestDate before: " + testDate);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
editor.putString("testdate", gson.toJson(testDate));

System.out.println("TestDate String after: " + pref.getString("testdate", null));

LocalDate newtestDate = gson.fromJson(pref.getString("testdate", null), new TypeToken<LocalDate>(){}.getType());

System.out.println("TestDate as Date after: " + newtestDate);
```

Output I get:

```
I/System.out: TestDate before: 2021-03-27
I/System.out: TestDate String after: {}
I/System.out: TestDate as Date after: 0000-00-00
```

Comment: why did you want to put as `toJson`?

Comment: @Ticherhaz I use it to make a string that can be put in shared preferences. Is that not necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `commit()` or `apply()` your `SharedPreferences.Editor` changes for them to actually be there in the `SharedPreferences` for reading.

In addition, gson out of the box does not know how to serialize `LocalDate`s. You need a custom `TypeAdapter` for that. See [Serialize Java 8 LocalDate as yyyy-mm-dd with Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192945/serialize-java-8-localdate-as-yyyy-mm-dd-with-gson)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I don't how I missed that in the testing code. Sadly I do `commit()` in the actual code for the app, so there seems to be an additional problem. I added commit() to the test code and now the return is still empty (seems reset)```I/System.out: TestDate before: 2021-03-27
I/System.out: TestDate String after: {}
I/System.out: TestDate as Date after: 0000-00-00```

Comment: Oh ok so if I have an instance of some class that contains a LocalDate, I can't serialize that instance without "loosing" the LocalDate value in it? Do I have to take the LocalDate Variable out and serialize it on its own?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [@lato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101361/laalto)'s awesome answer, there is a major difference in use-case between SharedPreferences.Editor's `commit()` and `apply()`.

`commit()` is synchronous and it returns a boolean which indicates success or failure.

`apply()` is asynchronous, faster and it doesn't return anything. The function was added in 2.3 as an improvement over commit() and is thus, the option of choice for more efficient code.