# Serialise LocalDateTime with gson and ISO_INSTANT generates error: Unsupported field

Tags: java, json, gson, java-time

Have a java object with a LocalDateTime property that I want to serialize and deserialize with gson.
I am using ISO_INSTANT as the format for datetime in the json output

Have tried creating a TypeAdaptor for GSON with the help from this post

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39193077/1196875

But get "Unsupported field: InstantSeconds"

Maybe I have gotten the date conversion messed up?

```
class LocalDateTimeSerializer implements JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(LocalDateTime date, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                return new JsonPrimitive(
                        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withLocale(Locale.getDefault()).format(date)); // "yyyy-mm-ddThhMMssZ"
        }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is unrelated to Gson, it also occurs when just running the date formatting code:

```java
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now()
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT
  .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
  .withLocale(Locale.getDefault())
  .format(date);
```

Exception:

```java
Exception java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: InstantSeconds
    at LocalDate.get0 (LocalDate.java:709)
    at LocalDate.getLong (LocalDate.java:688)
    at LocalDateTime.getLong (LocalDateTime.java:718)
    at DateTimePrintContext$1.getLong (DateTimePrintContext.java:205)
    at DateTimePrintContext.getValue (DateTimePrintContext.java:308)
    at DateTimeFormatterBuilder$InstantPrinterParser.format (DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:3459)
    at DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format (DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2402)
    at DateTimeFormatter.formatTo (DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    at DateTimeFormatter.format (DateTimeFormatter.java:1823)
    at (#5:1)
```

It appears (based on [this comment](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8171199?focusedCommentId=14032023&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14032023)) that you should [convert the `LocalDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#of(java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.ZoneId)) before formatting it.