LocalDate to JsonObject serialization (Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException)
I am having a dateField which is in this format and of type java.time.LocalDate - "dateField":"2024-06-11" in one of the classes.
Class is "ObjectClass"
I am trying to serialize this into a json string (dateField should be a jsonobject). I use Adapter for LocalDate serialization because without a custom adapter, it gives me issues with conversion but I want the json to be converted to jsonobject date with {year: month: day}
I use .toJson(ObjectClass) from GSONbuilder to build the message.
Expected - {"id":"03339302020230232020","refnumber":"89132C28C756DC","source":"SSS","dateField":{"year":2024,"month":6,"day":10}}
Right now dateFIeld is just a string -- {"id":"03339302020230232020","refnumber":"89132C28C756DC","source":"SSS","dateField":"2024-06-10"}
I get this error in another app when we try to parse this.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 14 column 17 path $.dateField; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 14 column 17 path $.dateField

Add the code sample to the question, it is quite hard to understand your question.

@K0cur Nothing quite hard if you're aware of how Gson works.

@user2868864 In short, Gson is mostly targeted on Java 6. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192945/serialize-java-8-localdate-as-yyyy-mm-dd-with-gson/53246168#53246168

@user2868864, can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example? It sounds like your custom serializer is not used but instead another custom one is used (since Gson by default does not serialize LocalDate in the format you have shown). But without a code sample it is difficult to provide any help.
