# Android: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I created an android applicatopn with a rest api. In here I used `gson` for the rest api and used `retrofit` to connect this rest api and android application.

In my application, I tried to get some data from the rest api by using an id. Then I got the following error log.(I didn't post my applicqation name with this error log).

Should I change some properties in rest api ? or any changes to application.  Currently I test my android application with rest api on localhost.

What should I do to handle this exception ?

This is my error log,

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1989-10-11
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:82)
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:35)
at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:36)
at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:24)
at retrofit.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:148)
at retrofit.OkHttpCall.access$100(OkHttpCall.java:29)
at retrofit.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:94)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:168)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1989-10-11" (at offset 10)
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:105)
... 17 more
```

**Update**

I found following code line in my retrofit call, I think this is the reason for the exception,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
       .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
       .create();
```

But I have no idea about convert this date format for common date format.

Currently I have no idea how to handle this exception . Have any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON - Date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format)

Comment: @AxelH : Thanks dude, for the link. +1 for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Its a variable Type mismatch Exception. Make sure the Type of variables in your model class and json response is same.
 In your case check for the Type of "Date" (you might have different name)variable.