# Gson: Serializing a class with two Date fields

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to serialize a class that has two `Date` fields defined:

```java
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateRange {
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    @Expose
    public Date startDate;
    @Expose
    public Date endDate;

    public DateRange(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public DateRange(String startDate, String endDate ) throws ParseException{
        this.startDate = dateFormat.parse(startDate);
        this.endDate = dateFormat.parse(endDate);
    }
}
```

but using `gson.toJson` an exception is thrown where multiple

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson

Gson gson = new Gson()
gson.toJson(new DateRange("2011-11-11", "2012-11-11"))
```

results in

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class java.text.DecimalFormat declares multiple JSON fields named maximumIntegerDigits
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
```

The problem is exacerbated where I have a class `ManyDates` which has a field with `DateRange` as well as another field with an array of `DateRange`. I have attempted adding the field as a `private transient` but no luck (also tried with the field as a `String` type)

```java
private transient java.text.DecimalFormat maximumIntegerDigits;
```

but the field is still causing issues with the serialization. I'm not sure where that field is even coming from but I suspect a simple solution to this must be just out of reach that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: The field most likely belongs to `java.util.Date`.  My recommendation would be to serialize the data as `String`s and deserialize it into a `Date`.

Comment: I think this is happens because you have to DataRange method and the argument you pass in toJson applicable for the two methods signature, what is the point of creating two methods?

Comment: I think that's because it tries to serialize dateFormat to json. Mark it with annotation @Transient.

Comment: You just have to make the `dateFormat` field `static`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format and remove the DateFormat from here

Comment: @MaximTulupov making dateFormat transient worked. Many thanks! If you post an answer I can mark it as correct. LyumbomyrShaydariv what would making it static do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case gson tries to serialize dateFormat field.

just annotate it with @Transient