# How to parse string to Date object using Gson, with original string format

Tags: java, json, gson

The string format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`, for example `2017-01-01 10:30`.

How to parse the string to date using Gson?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON - Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

Create Gson Object and pass Date format like this,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(YOUR_DATE_FORMAT).create();
```

Hope this may help you.