# NumberFormatException, from JSON to TypeToken (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, numberformatexception, typetoken

I have a data class that looks like this:

```
data class MyData (val myNumber : String,
                   var myDate   : Date?) : Serializable
```

When I set the date, I'm using a formatter, like the below:

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")
        cal.set(year.toInt(), monthNumber, day.toInt())
        myDate = cal.time
```

I am storing an array of this in SharedPreferences, and load it back like this:

```
private fun GetMyDataArray(): ArrayList<MyData>? {
    val json = sharedPrefs!!.getString(STORED_DATA_KEY, "")
    val caseType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<MyData>>() {}.type
    return Gson().fromJson<ArrayList<MyData>>(json, caseType)
}
```

99% of the time this works fine, but on some user's devices it is crashing with:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException Invalid number: Mar

Failed to parse date ["Mar 21, 2018 08:01:23']: Invalid number: Mar
com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse
```

Why on some devices does this work fine and others it doesn't?

Could it be due to user locale settings? and if so how would I fix that? (most of my users are in the USA, but some are in India and Europe)

Any pointers appreciated, thanks!

Comment: looks like your date doesn't have the right format. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format about setting a specific format for Gson to use (it's java but the idea is the same)

Comment: Thank you! I have been able to fix it :)