# Error with Gson().fromJson() depends on OS version

Tags: java, android, gson

I am writing android app with firebase DB and testing it on android api 22 and it's work, but when I try to launch it on api 26 (xiaomi mi 6) it's terminating. I guess the problem is with Gson().fromJson().

Error with api 26:

```
                      --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.user.easyshop, PID: 10051
                  com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Jul 17, 2018 11:35:06
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:87)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:75)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:46)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
                      at com.example.user.easyshop.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:64)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6665)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
                   Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["Jul 17, 2018 11:35:06"]: Invalid number: Jul 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:274)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:85)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:75) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:46) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) 
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927) 
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892) 
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841) 
                      at com.example.user.easyshop.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:64) 
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13) 
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2) 
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6665) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number: Jul 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parseInt(ISO8601Utils.java:311)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:129)
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:85) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:75) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.read(DateTypeAdapter.java:46) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82) 
                      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) 
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927) 
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892) 
                      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841) 
                      at com.example.user.easyshop.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:64) 
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13) 
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2) 
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6665) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10051 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

(com.example.user.easyshop.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:64) at) this error regarding my code:

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Item>>(){}.getType();
            List<Item> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class), listType); //this line
            Config.LIST = (ArrayList<Item>) yourClassList;

        }
```

My Item.class:

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item>{

    private String name;
    private boolean bought;
    private boolean deleted;
    private Date addDate;
    private Date operationDate;


    public Item(){
        this.name = "Item";
        bought = false;
        deleted = false;
        addDate = new Date();
        operationDate = null;
    }

    public Item(String name){
        this.name = name;
        bought = false;
        deleted = false;
        addDate = new Date();
        operationDate = null;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(@NonNull Item o) {
            int actual = isBought() ? 1 : 0;
            int other = o.isBought() ? 1 : 0;
            if(actual == other)
                return name.compareTo(o.name);
            else
                return actual - other;
        }
    ...
        }
```

As I said, everything work on other device. What can it be?

Comment: can u add your pojo here

Comment: check this line in the log cat   Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["Jul 17, 2018 11:35:06"]: Invalid number: Jul , your trying to pare string value to number that's why it is crashing

Comment: use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) on date field or this may help [Gson().setDateFormat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["Jul 17, 2018 11:35:06"]: Invalid number: Jul 
.....
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number: Jul
```

You can use dateFormat template for date parsing example:

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.setDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
.create();
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat