# notation Gson to formatter date in attribute DTO

Tags: java, jackson, gson, dto, serialization

I have the following code with Jackson:

```
public class Header implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("numeroUnico")
    private Integer numeroCliente;

    @JsonProperty("oficina")
    private Integer oficina;

    @JsonProperty("fecha")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    private Date fechaInscripcion;

}
```

this is my class "CustomDateSerializer.class"

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<Date> {

    private SimpleDateFormat formatter 
      = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

    public CustomDateSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public CustomDateSerializer(Class t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize (Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(formatter.format(value));
    }
}
```

They asked me to migrate all the implementations of Jackson to Gson.
Taking into account that the notation in Jackson @JsonProperty has an equivalence in Gson that is @SerializedName.
But for the notation in Jackson of:

```
@JsonSerialize (using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
```

What is its equivalent for Gson? if not, as it should be the implementation for attributes of type Date in my DTO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest and probably the only match is [`@TypeAdapter`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter). However you need to code either [`JsonSerializer<T>`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html) or [`TypeAdapter<T>`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) to be used with that annotation.

For example how to make something like your `CustomDateSerializer` see accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6873020/6413377).

Or maybe you can wrap your existing `CustomDateSerializer` with Gson `TypeAdapter<Date>` and use that in the annotation.

Comment: Did you find my answer useful? If you did consider accepting it. If you did not not please comment my answer. If you found better solution create a new answer based on it.