# Parsing Dates Gson: NumberFormatException

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm fairly new to java and Gson and I've been trying to parse some date from the nobelprize.org api. I've been able to parse through some of the info but when I include dates I seem to always hit errors. How would i go about fixing this error?

I've tried .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") but I still get the same error.

```
Gson mainparser = new GsonBuilder()
.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
.create();

mainparser.fromJson(line, ParsedJson.class);
```

```
public class ParsedJson {

    List<Laureates> laureates;

    public List<Laureates> getLaureates() {
        return laureates;
    }

    public void setLaureates(List<Laureates> laureates) {
        this.laureates = laureates;
    }


}
```

```
public class Laureates {
    int id;
    String firstname;
    String surname;
    Date born;
    Date died;
    String bornCountry;
    String bornCountryCode;
    String bornCity;
    String diedCountry;
    String diedCountryCode;
    String diedCity;
    String gender;
    List<Prizes> prizes;
...Getters/Setters

}
```

This is the error I get:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1845-03-27"

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1845-03-27"
```

*Edit: Example Json

```
    "laureates": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "firstname": "Wilhelm Conrad",
            "surname": "Röntgen",
            "born": "1845-03-27",
            "died": "1923-02-10",
            "bornCountry": "Prussia (now Germany)",
            "bornCountryCode": "DE",
            "bornCity": "Lennep (now Remscheid)",
            "diedCountry": "Germany",
            "diedCountryCode": "DE",
            "diedCity": "Munich",
            "gender": "male",
            "prizes": [
                {
                    "year": "1901",
                    "category": "physics",
                    "share": "1",
                    "motivation": "\"in recognition of the extraordinary services he has rendered by the discovery of the remarkable rays subsequently named after him\"",
                    "affiliations": [
                        {
                            "name": "Munich University",
                            "city": "Munich",
                            "country": "Germany"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
]
```

Comment: could you please post the json response

Comment: @Nomanaliabbasi Added in the edit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format check this

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You're sure `"id": "1"` works? It's defined as an `int` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `JsonDeserializer` for `Date` attributes.

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

   public DateDeserializer() {
   }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement element, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
        String dateStr = element.getAsString();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            return format.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

in your model class  add `JsonAdapter` for attributes

```
public class Laureates {
    int id;
    String firstname;
    String surname;
    @JsonAdapter(DateDeserializer.class)
    Date born;
    @JsonAdapter(DateDeserializer.class)
    Date died;
    String bornCountry;
    String bornCountryCode;
    String bornCity;
    String diedCountry;
    String diedCountryCode;
    String diedCity;
    String gender;
    List<Prizes> prizes;
...Getters/Setters

}
```

Comment: Dumb question but how do I implement the JsonDeserializer class from your answer. As I seem to either get this: DateDeserializer is not abstract and does not override abstract method, And also this from the @Override: Method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your question but. I think you thought `JsonDeserializer` is a custom class but it is `gson`'s class.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant to say how would I include DateDeserializer class, as currently it does not seem to override the method from JsonDeserializer and is giving me the not abstract/does not override errors from above

Comment: `JsonDeserializer` is not an abstract class. It is an interface. You shouldn't get any errors. I am not sure why you are getting that error. You just needed to create a java file and copy paste the  `DateDeserializer` class above.