# GSON issue with Map having java.util.Date as key

Tags: java, date, gson

I have a pojo in which I have `Map<Date, Object>`. When I try to serialize it using GSON, the date is serialized in UTC format. However, I want it serialized in the form Aug 23, 2000 12:00 AM.

I have tried setting the date format on GsonBuilder, but that does not come into effect. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please show how you are setting up `Date` serialization in GSON

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GSON - Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873020/gson-date-format)

Comment: Nope, I have tried all that is there in the linked question but it didn’t work.

Comment: If you can, use classes from the `java.time` package, instead of `Date`, as the latter is out*date*d.